# python web scraping - tags not found

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape some info from a website that requires a login.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time   
import requests
from lxml import html

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Applications/chromedriver')
driver.get("website/login")


#Login
username = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
username.send_keys('my email')

password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('my password')

form = driver.find_element_by_id('login-button')
form.submit()


#Search activities
driver.get('website/activities/search')

city = driver.find_element_by_name('location')
city.send_keys('London, England, United Kingdom')

key = driver.find_element_by_name('keywords')
key.send_keys('run')

activity = driver.find_element_by_name('activity_type')
activity.send_keys('Run')

search = driver.find_element_by_id('ride-search-button')
search.submit()


#Webscrape
pg = 15

for pg in range(1, pg): 
    print('page = ', pg)

    list_links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'activities')]")][1:10]
    print(list_links)

    for i, link in enumerate(list_links):

        driver.get(link)

        page = requests.get(link)
        htmlpg = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        try:
            item = htmlpg.find_all('strong')
            #Distance = ?? to be completed as item doe not find anything with 7.1 in it

        except:
            driver.back()
            continue

    driver.back()   

driver.quit()
```

The problem is that when I try to scrape the distance (7.1) using find_all, bs4 does not appear to find anything. It almost seems it is not parsing info on the current page (see html below).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you,
Fede

[image]

Comment: Without the webpage it is hard to say. But a few suggestions/questions for you: 1) Does the webpage include the value you want in the source HTML or is it dynamically generated via interaction in the webpage? This will determine whether you need bs4 or Selenium. 2) I would avoid using the strong tag to narrow down your search, instead search by a specific tag with specific class (e.g. soup.find('ul', {'class': 'inline-stats section'}).text)

Comment: Here's a tip: when you're having issues with finding elements in a web page, it often helps to save the page source to a file. You can then open it in Chrome using `file:///path/to/file.html` in the address bar. In my experience, logging in with selenium then using requests to get the pages individually doesn't work (certainly not always). In your case, I don't know why you're using requests at all since you're already getting the page using your web driver -- just do `htmlpg = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')`

Comment: Also I assume you're trying to iterate through pages, but I don't see your `pg` variable used anywhere

Comment: Thanks @rahfl23.
I can see the value 7.1 in the source html but not sire that's enough to say that it is not dynamically generated.
Also, thanks for your suggestionz

Feenstra, thanks for your tip!

In case you have any other comments on the code, feel free to shoot me a message.

Comment: I tried you suggestions. But noted that when I run the list_links loop, the list does not contain the current links on the page. This is strange.